# Why does member y get set to 0 in the following code?

Tags: c, struct, unions, static-initialization

I can't make out why this happens. I'm using a bunch of really complicated structures, unions, unnamed versions of both, static variables, etc... but I'm sure this should work. After a day of debugging, I've narrowed my problem to what happens in the following code. I'm using -fms-extensions, which doesn't seem to play nicely with this situation:

```
//main.c
//Why does y get set to 0 in the case of 'Breaks'?
//Compile with gcc -fms-extensions main.c

#include <stdio.h>

struct Base {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Extend {
    union {
        int X;
        struct Base;
    };
};

struct AlsoExtend {
    struct Base;
    int z;
};

static struct Extend Works = {
    .x = 5,
    .y = 3,
    //.X = 2
};

static struct Extend Breaks = {
    .x = 5,
    .y = 3,
    .X = 2
};

static struct AlsoExtend AlsoWorks = {
    .x = 5,
    .y = 3,
    .z = 69
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("Works: x:%d y:%d X:%d\n", Works.x, Works.y, Works.X);
    printf("Breaks: x:%d y:%d X:%d\n", Breaks.x, Breaks.y, Breaks.X);
    printf("AlsoWorks: x:%d y:%d z:%d\n", AlsoWorks.x, AlsoWorks.y, AlsoWorks.z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Found out that any time I initialize one of the members for the union, the others get 0'ed.

Am I missing the proper way to do this? (The initialization of a static structure setup like this?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [C99 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)  states this:

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the bytes of the object
>   representation that do not correspond to that member but do correspond to other members
>   take unspecified values.

Here, you write one value using one object of a union type and after you try to access the other object of this union type. This leads to unpredictable value in your type.

Thus, you can't do something like this. You should only use one object of the union for a same instance of a struct.

Comment: Well, that's my answer. It makes sense, and I see the reason for it, but it is unfortunate. In my particular usage of it, I've placed a dummy pointer at the start of a struct, and I would like apply a type to that pointer by using a union similar to the example. It does work, as far as how memory is laid out, and the operations on it. Infact, if I set the members in a function instead of the static variable above, it does work as intended. However, since it's not guaranteed, I'll just cast the pointer everywhere... and have less type-safety as a result... *sigh*

Comment: You want to have a special value to your pointer indicating it's a dummy pointer? Why not set it to `NULL` value for that purpose?

Comment: See also footnote 82, added to C99 in TC3.

Comment: @lbonn No, I don't want to indicate it's a dummy pointer, it's only a dummy pointer in the base structure so that I could reinterpret the pointer with a union in a later structure. I can just make it a void*, and cast it to whatever pointer it should be, but it's less elegant, and more error prone.

Answer (score 1):

As @lbonn says, you're abusing C!

`-fms-extensions` is a GCC specific option which turns on support for non-standard constructs, including otherwise impossible declarations such as those you attempt above.

The simple answer is:  "Don't do that!"  Seriously.  Don't use `-fms-extensions`, especially not for your own code!  Ever!

Writing declarations that conform to Standard C will hopefully make the problem easier to spot.

Read the text quoted in the answer given @lbonn carefully, and note that `0` is as good of an *unspecified value* as any other would be.

Comment: This is a great advice, but it's not a good answer. One can achieve the same bad result with a 100% compliant C99 - [take a look](http://ideone.com/gg9ztG).

Comment: Indeed, and once one does it correctly, then the problem is obvious, is it not?

Comment: It's easier to see, yes, but unless you know the specifics about accessing union members to which you did not write, it's not entirely obvious.

Comment: A decade later - For the record - I was exploring how advanced language features translated to pure C. Not only was it fun but it also led me into learning quite a bit about the linker and linker scripts.

Your rant about extensions, and "abuse" didn't at all point to the actual problem. Furthermore your comments about this construct being "impossible without them", then when shown they can, saying "Indeed, but....".

The only useful part of the answer are the parts pointing to lbonn's.

Comment: You're still way out far on a limb with one compiler's interpretation of another compiler's non-standard extensions.  There is still, all this time later, no "should work" about it.

Comment: The extensions have absolutely nothing to do with the problem here. The problem is quite simply that modifying a variant of a union, and accessing another variant is undefined in C. Its obvious with or without the extension. In no way am I interpreting any compilers extensions... I was simply assuming something about union access. Something, that very easily could have been defined. There is nothing hardware-wise that prevents it.

And infact, it did work, all day long without certain optimizations.

I learned quite a bit about OOP by re implementing it in C macros. So whatever, I'll do me

Comment: Furthermore, extensions exist for a reason. As much as you may have some personal moral objection to their use - obviously a ton of people disagreed - hence the existence and usage of the extension. It's a syntactic sugar at best.

Your answer provided no useful information. Sorry.

Lol If you'd seen the actual macros I was writing and using this in you'd have had a heartattack.

Comment: Finally, if anyone is interested in _why_ a language might leave this undefined, is to avoid a read/modify/write on the union. If you specifically leave it undefined, then it's not a worry, single write and you're done. Or whatever the compiler wants to do. :shrug: In my case I was actually placing the union variants on specific address boundaries, but that wouldn't _always_ be the case.

Certainly not something that _has_ to be in any way, just C being full of UB. I recommend using rust for this stuff now anyway. Beautiful language.